# Junit Tests run locally but not in Github actions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, junit

I am trying to run JUnit tests on GitHub Actions but it fails. On the contrary, locally all tests passed.

this is the TestClass :

```
package dsi.senior;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import dsi.senior.entities.ArchiveMedication;
import dsi.senior.entities.ArchiveSenior;
import dsi.senior.entities.IngredientsCategories;
import dsi.senior.entities.Meal;
import dsi.senior.entities.Medication;
import dsi.senior.entities.Senior;
import dsi.senior.repositories.ArchiveDao;
import dsi.senior.repositories.SeniorDao;
import dsi.senior.services.ArchiveMedServiceImpl;
import dsi.senior.services.IArchiveSeniorService;
import dsi.senior.services.IMealService;
import dsi.senior.services.IMedicationService;
import dsi.senior.services.ISeniorServiceImpl;
import dsi.senior.services.IngredientsCategoriesServiceImpl;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SeniorCareApplicationTest {


    @Autowired
    ISeniorServiceImpl seniorServiceImpl;
    @Autowired
    IArchiveSeniorService archSeniorService;
    @Autowired
    IMedicationService medicationService;
    @Autowired
    IMealService mealService;
    
    @Autowired
    ArchiveMedServiceImpl archiveMedServiceImpl;
    @Autowired
    IngredientsCategoriesServiceImpl ingCategoryImpl;
    
    @MockBean
    SeniorDao seniorDao;
    @MockBean
    ArchiveDao archiveDao;
    
    private static final Logger l = LogManager.getLogger(SeniorCareApplicationTest.class);

    Senior senior1 = new Senior("Hamdi","mzoughi","1997-05-3","male","09632455","51236987",
            "houmet saboun","single","reading","",76,180);
    
    Senior senior2 = new Senior("Chaima","mzoughi","1930-04-3","female","09632355","21236987",
            "Centre D'accueil Gammath","single","reading","",66,170);
    
    Senior senior3 = new Senior("Bilel","Nafati","1933-04-3","male","09732355","51116987",
            "Centre D'accueil Gammath","single","watching","",86,185);
    
    @Test
    public void retrieveAllSeniorTest() {
        when(seniorDao.findAll()).thenReturn(Stream
                .of(senior2,senior3).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        assertEquals(2,seniorServiceImpl.retrieveAllSenior().size());
    }
    
    
    
    /*
    @Test
    public void testAddSenior() {
        Senior s = seniorServiceImpl.addSenior(senior3);
        l.info("Senior added");
        Assertions.assertTrue(  seniorDao.findById(s.getId()).isPresent(),"ADD SENIOR FAILED !");
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByResidance() {
        
        
        List<Senior> seniors = seniorServiceImpl.findByResidance("Centre D'accueil Gammath");
        Assertions.assertTrue((seniors.size())>0,"seniors residance not founded");
        if (seniors.size()>0) {
             
             l.info("seniors residance founded"); } else { l.warn("warning check your method");

    }
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testDeleteSenior() {
        Senior s = seniorServiceImpl.addSenior(senior2);
        l.info("Senior added");
        Assertions.assertTrue(  seniorDao.findById(s.getId()).isPresent(),"ADD SENIOR FAILED !");
        seniorServiceImpl.deleteSenior(s.getId());
        l.info("Senior deleted");
        Assertions.assertFalse(  seniorDao.findById(s.getId()).isPresent(),"DELETE SENIOR FAILED !");
    
    }

    @Test
    public void testajouterMedicToArchive() {
        Senior s1 = seniorServiceImpl.addSenior(senior1);
        l.info("Senior added with id :  " + s1.getId());
        LocalDate dateObj = LocalDate.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = dateObj.format(formatter);
        String idA = "arch-" + s1.getId() + "-" + date;
        ArchiveSenior archSenior = new ArchiveSenior(idA, date, false, false, false, s1);
        archSeniorService.updateArchive(archSenior);
        l.info("Senior archive added with id :  " + idA);
        Medication medic = new Medication("Medic1", 3, "pills", date, date, s1);
        medicationService.newMedication(medic);
        l.info("Senior archive added with id :  " + idA);
        archiveMedServiceImpl.ajouterArchiveMedic(idA, medic.getIdmed(), false);
        l.info("Senior med affected to his archive ");
        Set<ArchiveMedication> archMeds = archiveMedServiceImpl.getAllMedsByArchive(idA);
        Assertions.assertTrue( archMeds.size() > 0,"assignment Med to archive fail");
        if (archMeds.size() > 0) {
            l.info("Medication found in Archive");
        } else {
            l.warn("warning check your method : AjouterMedicToArchive");
        }
    }
*/
    /*********************** CHEF TESTS **************************/
/*
    @Test
    public void testgetAllCategories() {
        List<IngredientsCategories> ingCatList = ingCategoryImpl.getAllCategories();
        assertEquals(8, ingCatList.size());
        if (ingCatList.size() == 8) {
            l.info("Ingredients Category is 8");
        } else {
            l.warn("warning check your method : getAllCategories");
        }
    }
    @Test
    @Rollback(true)
    public void testupdateMeal() {
        Meal meal = mealService.getMealById(7);
        meal.setDescription("new Description Test");
        mealService.updateMeal(meal, meal.getId());
        Meal updatedMeal = mealService.getMealById(7);
        Assertions.assertTrue((updatedMeal.getDescription())==("new Description Test"));
        if (updatedMeal.getDescription() == "new Description Test") {
            l.info("Meal updated succesfully");
        } else {
            l.warn("warning check your method : updateMeal");
        }
    }
*/
}
```

and this is my Pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>dsi.senior</groupId>
    <artifactId>SeniorCare</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SeniorCare</name>
    <description>Backend SeniorCare</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <sonar.organization>omario1414</sonar.organization>
        <sonar.host.url>https://sonarcloud.io</sonar.host.url>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
            <version>8.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- attached to Maven test phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and i'm trying to pass those tests in a CI/CD pipeline using GitHub Actions and this is the Workflow file :

```
#Workflow name
name: CI/CD Pipeline
on:
  #Manually trigger workflow runs
  workflow_dispatch:
  #Trigger the workflow on push from the main branch
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  #Test's job
  tests:
    name: Unit tests
    #Run on Ubuntu using the latest version
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    #Job's steps
    steps:
      #Check-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your workflow can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      #Set up JDK 11
      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '11'
      #Set up Maven cache
      - name: Cache Maven packages
        #This action allows caching dependencies and build outputs to improve workflow execution time.
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.m2
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-m2-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-m2
      #Run Tests
      - name: Run Tests
        run: mvn -B test
```

at first maven does not find Junit tests to run but now it shows this error  (full log [here](https://github.com/omario14/BackendSeniorCare/actions/runs/3289578734/jobs/5421283670))

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: 
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  SeniorCareApplicationTest.retrieveAllSeniorTest » IllegalState Failed to load ...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  18.190 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-10-20T12:22:12Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project SeniorCare: There are test failures.
Error:  
Error:  Please refer to /home/runner/work/BackendSeniorCare/BackendSeniorCare/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Error:  -> [Help 1]
Error:  
Error:  To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Error:  Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error:  
Error:  For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error:  [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: This looks to me like your springboot TEST settings are not right.  It looks like it is trying to communicate with your datasource, and not a mock.   If you want to verify that it fails locally as well when  you run tests, shutdown your localhost database instance, and run your test.  See if it also tries to connect to the datasource, or uses mock

Also remove the `RunWith`  you dont need it with SpringbootTest

Comment: Thanks for the quick response...
Yes its the same problem when i close database server !
how to solve that ?

Comment: Your _unit_ tests should use an integrated in-memory like H2. That should be initialized before the tests start. Spring Boot can do that using Liquibase or Flyway. If you want to run tests against this actual database server, those are no longer unit tests but _integration_ tests (end-to-end tests, etc.). These should _not_ run on GitHub, because obviously the database server is not available there.